# Variables not loading into javascript until refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a strange situation in which I echo php variables into javascript to use it with jquery. However, the variables are not defined when I open the page for the first time, and when I refresh the page or just go to the same link again, the variables are loaded.

Echoed in the javascript it looks like

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                console.log('test');
                window.GlobalVar = {show_table : "<tr><td>%.0f</td><td>%s</td><td>&#8364; %0.02f</td><td>&#8364; %0.02f</td><td><a href=''><img class='delete_task' src='/brugginkadmin/public_html/images//icons/delete.png' data-id='%s'></a></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='delete_query' value='%s'></td></tr>"};
            });
   </script>
```

And in later jquery functions they are not reconized, until refresh.

I've included jquery before these scripts.

In conclusion:
The problem is that this variable window.GlobalVar.show_table is not defined later on in the javascript, however after hitting refresh, it is.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.. Where is the php code?

Comment: How is this related to PHP?

Comment: Im sorry, too fast in selecting tags. The window.GlobalVar row is echoed with php. But I think that is not the problem. The problem is that this variable window.GlobalVar.show_table is not defined later on in the javascript, however after hitting refresh, it is.

Comment: It could totally be the problem. If the data is changing between refreshes. Could be a cache issue.

Comment: You could try setting no-cache headers with PHP.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I already added the no-cache header in the php file, without any help. However, all my JS is present in separate .JS files, and the instantiation happens in the header, maybe this can give a problem?

Comment: Where are you trying to access the property such that it appears undefined?

Comment: In the head, the code above is present. Below this block a JavaScript file with the jquery script is called. In this file, after a document ready statement the global variable is needed as a template to insert Ajax responses in a table

Answer (score 0):

Echoing PHP inside script tags causes odd and inconsistent behaviour. Build the entire script, tags and all, in php then echo to the page and see if that works better.

```
var script = <<<SCR
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                console.log('test');
                window.GlobalVar = {show_table : "<tr><td>%.0f</td><td>%s</td><td>&#8364; %0.02f</td><td>&#8364; %0.02f</td><td><a href=''><img class='delete_task' src='/brugginkadmin/public_html/images//icons/delete.png' data-id='%s'></a></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='delete_query' value='%s'></td></tr>"};
            });
   </script>
SCR;
echo script;
```